# Can't console.log(req.flash("error")) and render message at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

In the `get` section I have the console.log() commented. Because of that I receive the appropriate message on the screen. but if I uncomment it I receive the message in the console like this  `[message]` but no message outputted to the screen. why is that? can I not have 2  `req.flash('error')` in a route handler?

```
app.get("/login", function(req, res){
    // console.log(req.flash("error"))
    res.render('login', { message: req.flash('error') });
})

app.post("/login", function(req, res, next){
    console.log("posted")
    passport.authenticate("local",{
        successRedirect : "/users/" + req.body.username,
        failureRedirect : "/login",
        failureFlash : true
    })(req, res, next)
} )
```

im using `var flash = require("connect-flash");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `connect-flash` package states [(link)](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash), messages are cleared after used, so when You console log one (and use it), it's cleared and when You call it once more in route/middleware it's already empty.

**EDIT:** If You want to use one flash message more then once maybe it's possible to store it in some local variable and then both console.log it and use in response, but it's just a guess. I don't have enviroment set up right now to check it.